# Breaking 10 td's in set of 5 inside tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a page from external site where i have no control. Now the table has something like this:

```
    <table><tbody>
<!-- headers -->
<tr><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
<!-- body -->
<tr><td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I am getting this all TD's in all one line. now with jquery I want to fix this, with every 5 counts of TD, it should add the closing `</tr>` and add a opening `<tr>` and the remaining TD's should come inside them

Trying some like this:

```
if($("#container").find("table>tbody>tr>td").length <=5)){
do the breaking here 
}
```

Here is an Update, i forgot to mention: the first row always rows always contain the lables within td's and the second reow always contain the data, i tried something like this:

```
$('#mypahe form table>tbody>tr:odd').each(function(){
    $('<tr>').insertAfter(this).append($('>:gt(4)',this))
});
```

but it started with the labels all on the same line and in the below part, it break the tr into two tr's

I Updated question where the code I tried and U gave works only on the first portion and it never works on second tr

Comment: Use it like that way....$( "tr td:nth-child(5)" ).append( "<span> - 2nd!</span>" );

Comment: guys u there, please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this for example:

```js
$('#container table td:gt(4)').wrapAll('<tr>').parent().appendTo('#container table tbody');
```

```css
td {border: 1px #DDD solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPD**. Since the table also includes a header row the code can be generalized:

```
$('#container table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:gt(4)').wrapAll('<tr>').parent().appendTo('#container table tbody');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/06qofna8/2/

Comment: did u checked my question again, it is working but now it shows headers on two rows at top and the form fields in bottom 2 tow rows, like headers are not with the firld as it should me, its a bit complex piece of code which i am lost

Comment: i added fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/06qofna8/ of your code by adding headers too, if you see headers running different from what i am trying: i want under every header the value of that should go

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
$('table').find('tr').each(function() {
    // collect all cells with an index greater 4
    var newCells = $(this).find('td:gt(4)'),
        // add a row below current
        newRow = $('<tr>').insertAfter(this);
    // add new row
    newRow.append(newCells);
});
```

basically you loop over each row, grep the relevant cells and append them to a new row. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgvunzf9/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
function groupUp(TRelement, groups) {
    var trs = [];
    var groupSize = Math.floor(TRelement.children.length / groups);
    for (var i = 0; i < groups; ++i) {
        trs[i] = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < groupSize; ++j) {
            trs[i].appendChild(TRelement.children[0]);
        }
    }

    while (TRelement.children.length > 0) {
        trs[groups - 1].appendChild(TRelement.children[0]);
    }

    var table = TRelement.parentNode;
    table.removeChild(TRelement);
    trs.forEach(function (element) {
        table.appendChild(element);
    });
}

var trs = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; ++i){
    groupUp(trs[i], 2);   
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/oq44q48q/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that way...It will Surely Resolve your issue.

> $( "tr td:nth-child(5n)" ).each(function() { $(this).append( "HTML" );} );

OR

> $( "tr td:nth-child(5n)" ).append( "HTML" );

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but why we are using -2nd

Comment: This is only content. Replace this content with any which you want.

Comment: Just use this $( "tr td:nth-child(5)" ). logics.

Comment: There is no such thing as `-5th!`. It will just append a string literally.

Comment: Just replace this -5th! with html you want to add after the 5th td.

Comment: Of course it will not work, it will just append something to the `td:nth-child(5)`. You will not be able to append `</tr><tr>` and have it working.

Comment: Please try the updated code surely it will resolve your issue.

Comment: check my updated questions, it has two rows and headers should follow the fields parallel to them, that is where i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try something like this:

```
if($("#container").find("table>tbody>td").length <=5){    


 var theElements = $("#container").find("table>tbody>tr>td");    
    var theOutput = '';    
    $('tbody').empty();        
    $('tbody').append('<tr>');    
    for(var i = 1; i <= theElements.length + 1; i++) {    
        theOutput +=  theElements[i-1];    
        $('tbody').append(theElements[i-1])    
        if(i%5 == 0) {    
            $('tbody').append('</tr><tr>');    
        }    
    }     
    $('tbody').append('</tr>');    
}
```

Comment: it is working fine, but the issue is, it splits the td's, but it shows headers one after the another one and the form fields seperate, so isn't it is possible when we split the td's the second's form values should appear underneath it, else they are loadting